# A question about Bernoulli process ( maybe conceptual)?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Question:

Al performs an experiment comprising a series of independent trials. On each trial, he simultaneously flips a set of three fair coins.

Whenever all three coins land on the same side in any given trial,Al calls the trial asuccess.
i. Find the PMF for K, the number of trials up to, **but not including**, the second success.
ii. Find the expectation and variance of M, the number of tails that occur **before** the first success.

The given answer:

i. The second order Pascal PMF for random variable N, as defined in the text, is the probability of the second success comes on the nth trial. Thus, the random variable, K, is a shifted version of the second order Pascal PMF, i.e. $K = N − 1$. So, the probability that 1 success comes in the first k trials, where the next trial will result in the second success, can be expressed as:
   $ p_{K}(k) = \binom{k}{1}(\frac{1}{4})^2 (\frac{3}{4})^{k-1} , \quad k\geq1 $

**My confusion: The question says *not including the second success*, why the answer muplities another $(\frac{1}{4})$? , I think it is included in the second success. Is the answer wrong?**

ii. The number of tails before the first success, $ M$, can be written as a random sum:
$M = X_1 + X_2 + ··· + X_N$,
where $X_i$ is the number of tails that occur on(unsuccessful)trial i, and N is the number of unsuccessfultrials(i.e. trialsbeforethe firstsuccess). Wenoticethat X is equally likely to be either 1 or 2, and that N is a shifted geometric: $N = R − 1$, where R is a geometric random variable .

**My confusion:  Why is $N$ is shifted geometric distribution? *Before the first success..* which means that the success $p$ is not included , so the R & N are not the geo. distribution.**

I hope that my confusion can be answered. Thanks!

Comment: Calculate $p_K(1)$ and $p_K(2)$ yourself and compare them with the given solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i) the answer is correct. The extra factor $\frac14$ is the probability that there is a succes at the $k+1$-th trial, wich is needed for arriving at $K=k$. This together with one success in the preceding $k$ trials.
$$P\left(K=k\right)=$$$$P\left(\text{one success in the first }k\text{ trials}\wedge\text{success on the }k+1\text{-th trial}\right)=$$$$P\left(\text{one success in the first }k\text{ trials}\right)\times P\left(\text{success on the }k+1\text{-th trial}\right)=$$$$\binom{k}{1}\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k-1}\times\frac{1}{4}$$

ii) I don't really understand your confusion. $R$ denotes the number of trials needed to come to the first success. It has [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) corresponding with the first bullet that you encounter in the link. Then $N=R-1$ is the number of failures that precede this first success. It has geometric distribution corresponding with the second bullet in the link.

Comment: i.) What does the *not including the second success* in the question mean? Why do you mutliply the extra $1/4$ for the second success?

Comment: ii.) I think the **before** in the question means that the success is not included. So it is not a geometric distribution

Comment: i) To open up your mind let's look at special case $P(K=2)$. When will that occur? Two possibilities: $SFS$ or $FSS$. Probability on this: $\binom21\left(\frac14\right)^2\frac34$, so **twice** the factor $\frac14$. Do you agree? Do you agree with the calculation of $P(K=k)$ in my answer? ii) It is said that $R$ has geometric distribution and $R=N+1$ does include the first success. Btw, there are two sort of geometric distributions (see my link). One counting failures (not including success) and one counting trials (including success).

Comment: Oh!! It seems that the probability **p** of success is included whether the *"success"* is included.. I understand!!! Thank you so much!